# Dynamic / interpolated variable names from array of strings

Tags: go, variables, interpolation

Is it possible to take a `[...]string{}` and then loop over each string to create a new variable where the variable name is the string?

I can do this using interpolation with some other languages, but I'm kind of a golang newbie.

Comment: No this is not possible with Go.

Comment: A variable "name" is just what you've typed in the source, but if you're generating values at runtime you can't type those into the source to create a new variable name, so this would be a pointless exercise. There's probably another way to do what you want, but we can't tell what the actual problem is to be solved.

Comment: How would you then reference any of those variables? Go has no variable variable references, for example. Perhaps what you want is just a `map[string]something`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Go provides no way to dynamically create variables.